# How to prevent content hiding under the header when resizing the window height

Tags: html, css

I have split screen, one is background image and the other one is content with text and button. Both of them are taking full screen.

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="brand__name"><a href="#">LOGO</a></div>
    <div class="navbar__links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/google" class="signin">Sign In
          <span class="g_icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <nav>
 </header>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex__left">
    <h1 class="heading__title">TEXT</h1>
    <h2 class="h2__title">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</h2>
    <h3 class="h3__title">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</h3>
    <button class="flex__button__createroom" type="button" name="createRoom" id="createRoom">
    <span>Create room</span>
    </button>
 </div>

 <div class="flex__right"></div>
 </div>

//header
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 68px;
    box-shadow: 0 -0.4rem 0.9rem 0.2rem rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#1C1B29, #242230);
    color: #444444;
}

.row .flex__left, .row .flex__right {
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: calc(100vh - 68px);
}

.row .flex__right {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(i put image here);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The problem is when I try to resize my window height, the content with text and button go under the header. I want it to stop moving once it reaches header.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't seem to include the navbar you are describing. You can use the "snippet" tool when editing your question to put together a runnable example of your problem (which makes it much easier for us to answer the question, and generally gets you better/faster responses)

Comment: added html navbar